# using customize slider on Joomla its working fine on my machine giving trouble on hosting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I got joomla website .. need to maintain it ..
its my first experience working around with joomla .
its a template i need to add slider .. i try to find out good module but i cant find any good slider on joomla so i got slider i want to add this on joomla templete i did add this on my local machine and its working fine but when i add this code to server its not working any suggestion  even i just made my own modal its also not working

here is the code for slider

```
<div id="zf1" class="zoomflow">
            <div class="items">
                <div  class="item-tobe" data-source="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/margalla.jpg">
                    <div style="" class="captionCon">
                        <div style="  padding-top: 10px;
      padding-right: 59%;left: 0px; bottom: 10px; height:100px; width: 100%;" data-delay="" data-effect="slidebottom fade" class="caption bg-lightblue style_noir"><strong>Margalla Hill &amp; National Park</strong> - Sponsored by The Dawood Foundation Click here to View<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 590, y: 440}}" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/105872235?color=a8a8a8" class="films-play-btn-01 modal">  </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-tobe" data-source="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/chitral.jpg">
                    <div style="" class="captionCon">
                        <div style="  padding-top: 10px;
      padding-right: 59%;left: 0px; bottom: 10px; height:100px;width: 100%;" data-delay="" data-effect="slidebottom fade" class="caption bg-lightblue style_noir"><strong>Chitral Gol &amp; National Park</strong> - Sponsored by The Dawood Foundation  Click here to View<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 590, y: 440}}" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/105873756?color=a8a8a8" class="films-play-btn-01 modal"> </a> 
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-tobe" data-source="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/3.jpg">
                    <div style="" class="captionCon">
                        <div style="left: 0px; bottom: 10px; width: 100%;" data-delay="" data-effect="slidebottom fade" class="caption bg-lightblue style_noir"><strong>The Give Back Project</strong> - Sponsored by <a href="http://bit.ly/nM4R6u" target="_blank"> -  </a> 
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-tobe" data-source="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/1.jpg">
                    <div style="" class="captionCon">
                        <div style="left: 0px; bottom: 10px; width: 100%;" data-delay="" data-effect="slidebottom fade" class="caption bg-lightblue style_noir"><strong>The Give Back Project</strong> - Sponsored by <a href="http://bit.ly/nM4R6u" target="_blank"> -  </a> 

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-tobe" data-source="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/img/2.jpg">
                    <div style="" class="captionCon">
                        <div style="left: 0px; bottom: 10px; width: 100%;" data-delay="" data-effect="slidebottom fade" class="caption bg-lightblue style_noir"><strong>The Give Back Project</strong> - Sponsored by <a href="http://bit.ly/nM4R6u" target="_blank"> -  </a> 

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                        <!--   Hide this for slider test
                        <div class="docu-thumbnails-wrapper">
                            <a href="https://vimeo.com/105873756" class="chitral-docu-link" target="_blank">Documentary Thumbnail</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="docu-thumbnails-wrapper">
                            <a href="https://vimeo.com/105872235" class="margallah-docu-link" target="_blank">Documentary Thumbnail</a>
                        </div>
                        -->
                    </div>



    <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/zoomflow/zoomflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script>
        /*
        jQuick(document).ready(function($){
            jQuick(".zoomflow").zoomflow({
                settings_slideshowTime:5
                });
    });
        */
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            jQuery("#zf1").zoomflow({
                settings_slideshowTime:5
                ,design_padding:150
                });
            jQuery("#zf2").zoomflow({
                settings_slideshowTime:5
                ,settings_mode:'only-two'
                ,design_padding:150
                ,design_ratio:"4:3"
                });
            jQuery("#zf-logos").zoomflow({
                settings_slideshowTime:5
                ,design_padding:150
                ,design_ratio:"1:1"
                });
    });
        </script>
```

here is the code for modal

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
var html = '<div class="header-unit"><a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="closePopup()"></a><div id="video-container"><video autoplay loop class="fillWidth mute"><source src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/video/provdo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video></div><!-- end video-container --></div><!-- end .header-unit -->';

   var docHeight = $(document).height();

   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'>"+html+"</div>");

   $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'position': 'fixed',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
      });

});



    });

     function closePopup(){

         $(".mute").trigger("pause");
          $('.mute').animate({
              left: '50%',
              top:'40%',
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '10px',
            width: '10px'

              },500,function(){
            $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');

        });
    }
</script>
```

both code working fine on my local machine but its not working on live server
i m getting these error and warning at live server .. 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
WARNING: Invalid network resource for ScrollMagic. Please use 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/1.3.0/jquery.scrollmagic.debug.js' instead!

Comment: Define **"not working"**. And please check your browser console and report any Javascript errors back here

Comment: i m getting these error and warning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined    WARNING: Invalid network resource for ScrollMagic. Please use 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/1.3.0/jquery.scrollmagic.debug.js' instead!

Comment: I would try adding the JS on your server and see if that fixes the problem, then you can isolate that is something with the cloudfare and your script.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla loads jquery in noconflict mode.

You have to change your code to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(function() {
      var html = '<div class="header-unit"><a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="closePopup()"></a><div id="video-container"><video autoplay loop class="fillWidth mute"><source src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/video/provdo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video></div><!-- end video-container --></div><!-- end .header-unit -->';
      var docHeight = jQuery(document).height();
      jQuery("body").append("<div id='overlay'>"+html+"</div>");
      jQuery("#overlay")
         .height(docHeight)
         .css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
            'width': '100%',
            'z-index': 5000
      });
   });
});
function closePopup(){
     jQuery(".mute").trigger("pause");
     jQuery('.mute').animate({
       left: '50%',
       top:'40%',
       opacity: '0.5',
       height: '10px',
       width: '10px'
       },500,function(){
       jQuery('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
     });
}
```

Reference: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)